# Oracle how to select intervals

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, date, materialized-views

Imagine room with locked door. There are card reader near door. To open the door you need to put your card to cardreader.

I have 2 tables with events in my Oracle database -
entries ( door was opened from outside the room )
exits ( door was opened from inside the room )

All i want is to select presense intervals like 
employee 1 was in room at some day from 10:00 to 11:00 and from 12:00 to 18:00.

But there are 3 problems

1. Sometimes user opens the door but don't leave the room.
2. Sometimes one user opens the door and another user goes out with him while
   door is opened one time.
3. Data size (about 100k in each table)

And questions:

1. What is the best way to select presense intervals
2. Is there any way to create fast refreshable materialized view to solve this?

Here is sample

```
drop table entries;
drop table exits;

CREATE TABLE ENTRIES
(   
  "EVENTDATE" DATE NOT NULL, 
  "EVENTTIME" DATE NOT NULL, 
  "EMPLOYEEID" NUMBER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EXITS
(   
  "EVENTDATE" DATE NOT NULL, 
  "EVENTTIME" DATE NOT NULL, 
  "EMPLOYEEID" NUMBER NOT NULL
);


delete from ENTRIES;
delete from exits;

Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 08:44:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:18:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:19:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:22:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:37:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:38:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:39:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:40:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into ENTRIES (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 13:22:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));

Insert into EXITS   (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:40:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into EXITS   (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 12:36:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into EXITS   (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 11:55:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into EXITS   (EMPLOYEEID,EVENTDATE,EVENTTIME) values (8,to_date('01-AUG-13 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('01-JAN-00 18:02:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Desired result is something like:

```
"EMPLOYEID"   "EVENTDATE"            "ENTERTIME"              "LEAVETIME"
8            01-AUG-13 00:00:00    01-JAN-00 08:44:00      01-JAN-00 11:55:00
8            01-AUG-13 00:00:00    01-JAN-00 12:18:00      01-JAN-00 12:36:00
8            01-AUG-13 00:00:00    01-JAN-00 12:37:00      01-JAN-00 12:40:00
8            01-AUG-13 00:00:00    01-JAN-00 13:22:00      01-JAN-00 18:02:00
```

**Update**

If there are 2 enters in a row use first, ignore second. 
If there are 2 exits in a row use second, ignore first

Comment: What are the business rules that you want to implement?  If a user opens the door but does not exit, how do you determine when they actually exited?  If a user follows someone in, how do you determine that?  If you see that a user entered a time A and entered again at time B, how do you determine when the first interval ended (assuming the user exited with someone else)?  If you see that a user entered at A, exited at B, and exited at C, do you consider them to be present just between A and B? How do you know whether they opened the door without leaving or entered with someone else?

Comment: check the sample i provided. it is rather descriptive. In short if there are 2 enters in a row use first, ignore second. If there are 2 exits in a row use second, ignore first

Comment: Any reason why date and time are not being stored in same field?

Comment: to enable easy time filtering in different days. Is there any other way to easy achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below tested query:-

`SELECT employeeid,eventdate,entry_time,exit_time
FROM
(SELECT employeeid,eventdate,entry_time,exit_time,
rank() over (partition BY employeeid,eventdate,exit_time ORDER BY entry_time ASC) et
FROM
(SELECT t.employeeid,t.eventdate,t.eventtime entry_time,
o.eventtime exit_time,
 rank() over (partition BY t.employeeid,t.eventdate,t.eventtime ORDER BY o.eventtime ASC) mt
 FROM entries t,exits o
WHERE t.employeeid = o.employeeid AND t.eventdate=o.eventdate
AND t.eventtime < o.eventtime) WHERE mt =1)WHERE et=1`

u can test the same at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72ac2/9

Comment: Happy it worked for you!! It first maps all the eventtime from entries to all the greater eventime from exits . Then for each entry time it takes the closest exit time . then again for each exit time it takes the closest entry time

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test to see if this works and I ignored eventtime but try the below.
Basically, we want to find the true enters and true exits (true enter: enter/exit with no enter between, true exit: exit/enter with no exit between). We join the two (join the true exits twice) and show the enter/exit where exit is after enter and there are no other exits between the enter exit.

```
select
  a.employee_id
, true_enterdate
, true_exitdate
from (
select
  ent1.eventdate true_enterdate  -- enter/exit with no enter between
, employee_id
from
  entries ent1
  join exits ex1 using (employee_id)
  left outer join entries ent2 using (employee_id)
where 1=1
  and ent1.eventdate < ex1.eventdate  
  and ent2.eventdate > ent1.eventdate
  and ent2.eventdate < ex1.eventdate
  and ent2.employee_id is null 
) a join (  
select
  ent1.eventdate true_exitdate  -- exit/enter with no exit between
, employee_id
from
  entries ent1
  join exits ex1 using (employee_id)
  left outer join exits ex2 using (employee_id)
where 1=1
  and ent1.eventdate < ex1.eventdate  
  and ex2.eventdate > ent1.eventdate
  and ex2.eventdate < ex1.eventdate
  and ex2.employee_id is null 
) b using (employee_id)
left outer join (
select
  ent1.eventdate true_exitdate2  -- exit/enter with no exit between
, employee_id
from
  entries ent1
  join exits ex1 using (employee_id)
  left outer join exits ex2 using (employee_id)
where 1=1
  and ent1.eventdate < ex1.eventdate  
  and ex2.eventdate > ent1.eventdate
  and ex2.eventdate < ex1.eventdate
  and ex2.employee_id is null 
) c using (employee_id)(
where 1=1
  and true_enterdate < true_exitdate
  and true_exitdate2 > true_enterdate
  and true_exitdate2 < true_exitdate
  and c.employee_id is null;
```

Comment: after fixing parenthesis, and employee_id to employeeid it's still not working SQL Error: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier